# Can you redirect HTTP to HTTPS with a k8s Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I've tried everything on stack overflow and beyond and can't find a solution that works to redirect http to https. My current config is below.

My ingress is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-address
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: my-certificate
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 2400
```

And my service is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nodeweb
  ports:
  - name: my-service-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 2400
    targetPort: 2400
```

Comment: Mb this will help https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/

Comment: What ingress implementation do you use?

Comment: @zerkms I don't have a preference, I've tried with NGINX as in the example above.

Comment: @nickponline Since your redirection is working and throwing 404 errors, have you modified HTTP binding? Even if no source exists or required SSL were not enabled you will receive a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GKE (`1.17.13-gke.2600+`), find [this document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect) explaining how to configure FrontendConfig with http-to-https redirect. Then you [associate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#associating_frontendconfig_with_your_ingress) the FrontendConfig with your Ingress using `networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig` annotation.

Comment: Do I need to keep all the existing annotations I have in my current Ingress config?

Comment: I'd revert back to the embedded ingress controller, unless you need specifically nginx for some of its functionality.

Comment: Thanks @jabbson this works for redirecting http:// example.com to https:// example.com however http:// www.example.com gives an error "response 404 (backend NotFound), service rules for the path non-existent " - where as https:// www.example.com correctly goes to https:// example.com